# Android: how the unknown album, artist, genre of music will be displayed?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-player

I am developing a music application in Android, and when retrieving the album, artist, genre names of the songs, I get some unknown names.

For albums, the unknown album name is displayed as "music".
For artists, the unknown artist name is displayed as ""
and for Genres, the unknown genre is displayed as " "

Are these default names same on all the devices?? Because I want to rename those unknown names to more readable- Ex:"Unknown Artist" or "Unknown Album"

I had tried in only 2 devices and found that unknown album name is displayed as "music" BUT unknown artist name is displayed differently in both devices.

I would like to know how to handle these Unknown Names.

Comment: have You tried http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#UNKNOWN_STRING ?

Comment: Display whatever you want instead.  How about the file name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems You need [UNKNOWN_STRING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#UNKNOWN_STRING):

> The string that is used when a media attribute is not known. For example, if an audio file does not have any meta data, the artist and album columns will be set to this value.

I've checked MediaPlayer android code here and, actually by default it's doing the following steps:

- check if string from ContentProvider is UNKNOWN_STRING;
- if so, it get changed with some string from the resource (by I'd doubt that You really need that strings);

So, You need just to check data returned by ContentProvider for `MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING` and handle it whatever You like to. (e.g. provide the same string on all devices).
For example, checkout [com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackActivity.java#MediaPlaybackActivity) source, it has the following code:

```
if (MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING.equals(albumName)) {
    albumName = getString(R.string.unknown_album_name);
    albumid = -1;
}
```

Comment: In a song in my phone, I have a song with empty Album name(in meta-data). But when retrieving, the Android system itself displaying the album name as "music".

Comment: right, it's because mentioned by me UNKNOWN_STRING is "" (empty string) currently. Refer to my answer, I've provided some more details about logic of handling.

Comment: I have seen your code. MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING is from api level-8, but I'm developing it in api level-7. So I checked with statement - `if (albumName.equals(""))`. But it is not even going through this statement.

Comment: What do You mean by 'it is not even going through this statement'? Have You compiled it and provided 'somewhere' it could have a chance to be executed? Or is albumName equals null (this case could be easily treated as "")? And, some bad news: based on http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html only 3,7% of devices have API 7 now (and their number decreases every day).

Comment: I had tried it in API-8, 
`if(MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING.equals(albumName))`
`albumName = "Other";`
but still the unknown album-names are not displaying as "Other" It displaying by the default name "Music".

Comment: You need to change data in the media database at least to see another names or,  better, modify files itself.

Comment: I had already tried by modifying the meta-data of the song in my sys(Win XP). But no luck. Are there any chances that the phone manufacturer modified the native android code for this??

Comment: We probably have changed handling of Unknown string, but not its placing in the database (because mediastore is a public API), but where might be good chance that for example media databases were not refreshed properly.

Comment: the problem is with my phone: when retrieving the album name through MediaStore Cursor, the unknown album-name is displaying as "Music". BUT when displaying the `MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING`, it is showing "<unknown>".

Comment: is it > API-8? If so, then it's definitely OEM bug as far as I understand android API documentation.

Comment: yeah, my project minSdkVersion is 8. But I dont think its a BUG. May be the phone manufacturer set it like that. Because as I have observed now, unknown album-name is retrieved as "Music" but unknown artist-name is retreived as "<unknown>"(Android default string). May be the phone manufacturer himself changed it for ease. BUT THE CODE YOU HAVE PROVIDED IS THE RIGHT WAY TO DO. If the phone manufacturer doesnt provided such default string, it would have displayed as per our String.

Comment: And also plz remove the line `albumid = -1;` , because -1 is not an allowed value for album ID.

Answer (score 1):

If your audio media have no album metadata then android scanner sets the album name to the name of the folder containing your media.